# How to update data in a text file which is stored in local storage using java

Tags: java

I have text file in a local storage with some data. Now i need to update data for only selected line data.

```
This is my textfile data

    Kumar
    Gaaa
    9394769487
    Male
    Un Married
    Tue Jun 12 00:00:00 IST 1984
    kumar@gmail.com
    Kumar@1993
    rtyhrty
    India
```

here i am receiving new data from different fields.So i need to update 
 particular lines of data to related data only
 ex: Here first line is Name=kumar,
     i want to update Name=ajay

this is my reading logic and put all the values into HashMap object.
can you tell me any another process is there for putting all lines of data to particular key in a Map object.

```
                String temp;
                String[] line=new String[15];   
                InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(path);
                BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(stream));
                while((temp = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<line.length ;j++)
                    {   
                        line[j]=reader.readLine();

                        String fname=line[0];
                        String lname=line[1];
                        String mobile=line[2];
                        String gender=line[3];
                        String marry=line[4];
                        String dob=line[5];
                        String email=line[6];
                        String pwd=line[7];
                        String address=line[8];
                        String country=line[9];
                        String idcard=line[10];
                        String idfile=line[11];
                        String addcard=line[12];
                        String addfile=line[13];

                        map.put("fname",fname);
                        map.put("lname",lname);
                        map.put("mobile",mobile);
                        map.put("gender",gender);
                        map.put("marry",marry);
                        //map.put("dob",dob);
                        map.put("email",email);
                        map.put("address",address);
                        map.put("country",country);
                        map.put("idcard",idcard);
                        map.put("idfile",idfile);
                        map.put("addcard",addcard);
                        map.put("addfile",addfile);
                    }   
                }
                stream.close();
                reader.close();
```

Comment: For this (putting all lines of data to particular key in a Map object.), why don't you create another Map which will just store the map you have just create. fileMap.put("your file name", map_created_storing_line_data).

Comment: Can you give some idea as you said, here if i don't write for loop in a while the String value doesn't save in to Map object.Here i want index based read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map or read line by line both are efficient based on below scenario

1. If reading the file one time and editing the file as and when requirement comes is what you need then storing the data in static map(class level static variable) is your best solution.By doing this you don't need to read the file again and again whenever the modification for file comes change the value in map and overwrite the whole map data to file
2. If you want to read the file each time there is a modification request then the best thing to do is to read it line by line and modify the line for which the request came and then overwrite the file.It does not make sense to store the file data in map each time if you are going to read the file at every request.

Hope This Helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the file line by line, change what lines you need to change and write all lines to a new file, then delete the old file and rename new file. Unless the file is very large and you only need to change first few lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the file into a map
2. Alter the map
3. Write the map into the file